# Bootstrap validator form plugin: how to change feedback icons

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons, formvalidation-plugin

The [bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/) plugin helps validating the form fields providing a bunch of cool features. One of those features are the feedback icons, which defaults to glyphicon.

Suppose I want to replace glyphicon with font awesome.

The [documentation](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-usage) says they can be changed by passing a "feedback" JSON object as data attribute or via JavaScript.

Via JavaScript it's easy. But as data attribute, it is unclear where and how exactly add it, because simply adding:

```
feedback: {
  success: 'fa-check',
  error: 'fa-times'
}
```

as data attribute to the `<form>` or the `<div class="form-group">` or the `<input>` itself it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time struggling with it, I realized that the JSON feedback object should be added to the  element and also it needs to be added using this syntax (which was not specified in the docs):

```
<form ... data-feedback='{"success": "fa-check", "error": "fa-times"}'>
```

**Note the quotes syntax.**

Also, if we are not just changing the glyphicon but replacing it with a font-awesome one (like in my example), in the `<div class="form-group">` we need to replace:

```
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

with:

```
<span class="fa form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: I still do not get the quotes syntax part. Do you know why we have to do it this way?

Comment: well according to JSON syntax you have to: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: Okay, so it is a parsing thing to get json out of this data-tag-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very well documented, and I could not make it work. I ended up using a different form validator which accomplish the same functionality and it's **easier to configure success/error formats using bootstrap classes**:

```
 var validator = $('#submitForm').validate({ 
    validClass: "is-valid",
    errorClass: "is-invalid",
```

[image]

[jQuery Validator](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)