# How to override Bootstrap's Validation glyphicons with data-attributes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, overriding, bootstrapvalidator

Regarding to [this documents](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-options):

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-delay="".

But when I do this ...

```
<input 
data-feedback-error="glyphicon-remove-circle"
type="email" pattern="\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b"
class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" required/>
```

or

```
<input 
data-feedback="error:glyphicon-remove-circle"
type="email" pattern="\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b"
class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email" required/>
```

or

```
<span data-feedback-error="glyphicon-remove-circle"
  class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

or

```
<span  data-feedback="error:glyphicon-remove-circle"
 class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

... then it does not override the feedback-error default of `glyphicon-remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36979584/931358), you have to write the `data-feedback`-attribute to the form tag with a special quotes style:

> `<form ... data-feedback='{"success": "fa-check", "error":"fa-times"}'>`
>
> **Note the quotes syntax**.